# Magic - Applying Physics to Runes

Tags: magic, technology, physics, balancing-magic-systems, power-sources

I'm making a magic system, unsurprisingly, based on runes.

-

**Basic concept**:
Scribe a rune (e.g. a lightning rune), apply force to it (e.g. shoot it with a cannon), boom - lightning bolt.

-

**Problem**:
I want this to be applicable to necromancy by exchanging the blood (life energy) of one being to another. Blood transfusions, however, do not classify as 'applying force', as far as I'm aware.

-
**Question**:
While I could contrive some bullcrap new way of activating runes for a specific group of people, I'd rather keep it simple and consistent. I want for both the cannon shot and the blood to be able to activate the rune, however, I am extremely dumb in the ways of science, as you probably figured out. Should I change the activation factor to be Energy and not Force? Does this make sense in the scope of actual physics? Could a cannon shot give energy to a rune? Are there any alternatives to Energy and Force that I am too much of a business major to be aware of? All help is greatly appreciated. I hope you have a good day.

Comment: I don't think there is a hard science answer to this question about fictional magic system.

Comment: @VLAZ agree to disagree.

Comment: In that case, I'm looking to the scientific papers to cited for this.

Comment: @VLAZ Maybe I misrepresented my thoughts. I just want there to be one thing to power the magic system. Think of it as giving power to a battery, I'm wondering how that works in real life. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The [tag:hard-science] tag is defined as: "*Requires answers backed up by equations, empirical evidence, scientific papers, other citations, etc.*" So are you looking for answers that are required to give real scientific backing? If not, I'd suggest you remove the tag.

Comment: Questions don't have to make sense, answers do :p

Comment: Questions most certainly do have to make sense @Alot . OP, what you seem to need rather than the [tag:hard-science] tag is a [tag:hard-science-analogue] tag or [tag:technobabble]. Perhaps someone can make one for this express purpose, but the issue then would be sorting out what would constitute a "best answer" - the question needs to be sufficiently well defined to have a clear front-runner. At the moment we seem to have an anything goes situation where as long as it's technobabble then it fits equally well. Technobabble is aesthetic in nature and therefore opinion-based and off-topic.

Comment: See this meta post re: [technobabble](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6516/opinions-about-the-new-technobabble-tag) for info.

Comment: You say your necromancy is powered by blood. But what do the spells actually do?

Comment: I had a really hard time understanding as your problem section makes transfusion look like as both the trigger and the rune effect. But as far as I get it , you want us to think about one global trigger that can encompass both force and "transfusion". Thingy is, you don't detail how the transfusion trigger works. Do we just need to cut ourselves and bleed on it? Do we actually need to exchange blood with someone else? How much blood do we need to shoot a lightning bolt and can it be dried before usage? These are things you should devise so we can better aim what answer you need :).

Answer (score 6):

I currently have a 71 page document detailing how my runes work. Welcome to the hobby :p

I think the most important thing here is the preservation of potential energy, though if you going for blood, you going to need to go more loosely for "potential" then "potential energy".

With the cannon, you converting the kinetic energy of the charge (or cannonball?) into the electric potential energy of lightning.

There isn't really that much chemical potential energy in blood to convert - or wouldn't the necromancers feel dumb when they found out that strong acids worked better then blood.

Loosening the definition a bit, the thing that does contain incredible "potential" in blood is the genetic code contained within every cell which composes the blood. Every cell in your body contains the dna blueprint to generate your entire body in a chemical strand - that is an incredible amount of knowledge. If you willing to say there is some truth to "knowledge is power" in your world, the necromantic rune could be destroying the dna (and its knowledge) to convert that potential to a necromantic effect.

If you do go with something like this, there is a cool mundane effect you could do to the "used up" blood put through the necro runes. If the necro rune is using up the knowledge and structures of the cells in the blood to produce an effect, the necro rune would break the cells down from solid objects to a liquid. Blood is thicker then water, necro drained blood would no longer be thicker then water though :p

Comment: Now that's an answer. Very interesting thought with the DNA potential. Thank you sir/ma'am, and have a nice day.

Comment: And think futhurer. Sacrifice flesh give You more power. Blood do not have DNA in red cells. Meat have lots of it. And sperm is sooo powerful...

Comment: @Kamitergh But sperm is only half as powerful as other cells :-/

Comment: @Daron Sperm have lots of DNA per cell. Other cells have some other purpouses and DNA is only small part of them.

Comment: Just adding to the commentary, would stem cells be the end all be all of ultimate necromancy since they have the DNA to replicate your whole body?

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle Every cell in your body, except for gametes, certain lymphocytes, mature erythrocytes and probably some other exceptions I must be forgetting right now, has exactly the same DNA, so no.

Answer (score 3):

**Magically energy is an untapped physics variable**

In a way somewhat opposite to what you are asking, magical energy exists counter to physics rather than within it. However, that does not mean that they do not interact. Magic could essentially function as an untapped attribute of reality and runes somehow act as a means of accessing it. That said, there is no way to scientifically explain what those attributes might result in. The only thing that really makes sense from a scientific standpoint might be to modify existing physics equations by multiplying them by this variable of magical potential.

For example you could take the kinematic equations or the kinetic and potential energy equations and multiply them by some magical constant to determine magical potential. You as the author can then decide what magical potential is required for each magical act and then you end up with a certain result based on how the math works out.

[image]
[image]

The required potential and result don't necessarily have to be arbitrary either. You can take real historical examples of rituals conducted by historical societies and use that as a basis for what is required for certain magical affects. For example, the Mayans built the temple at Chichen-Itza was built over the top of a sinkhole so that they could throw in sacrifices to the gods for rain.
[image]

You could turn that into an equation calculating magical potential based on the kinetic impact of a body falling from the height of the temple to the base of the sinkhole. Using the free fall equation we can find the impact velocity of falling 50 m from the top of the temple is about 31 m/s, and since the average adult mass is about 136 lbs (62 kg), we can take the kinetic energy equation of 0.5 x (62kg) x (31m/s)^2 = 29791 J of kinetic energy. So multiply that by your magic potential constant for blood magic (Mcb) you could say perhaps that the necessary Magical Potential Energy (MPE) to control the weather. So ~3000 J kinetic energy times the Mcb is necessary to control the weather.

You could then compare different types of magic using the chosen constant, so if we say blood magic is super powerful we could maybe set the Mcb to 800, but nature magic might be more powerful so it has a Magic Potential Constant of Nature (Mcn) of  1200. The end result would be that controlling the weather takes 2.4M MPE (3000Jx800Mcb), but for someone who practices nature magic it only takes 2000 J of kinetic energy. Nature magic is therefore the obvious preferred option, but maybe blood magic is just more easily accessible because you have to somehow produce 2000 J of energy with a single seed instead of a whole tree or something.

Then you can just rinse and repeat for whatever magical type or ancient ritual you want to build into your story. Want a necromancer to raise an army of zombies? Maybe calculate the force exerted during a sneeze as real voodoo doctors used to poison people by blowing powder into their faces. The poison would cause comatose which would lead to families accidentally burying them alive. The witch doctor would then come dig up the body and revive them in a brain damaged state just conscious enough to follow basic instructions and suddenly they have a free plantation slave that everyone swears died last week. Multiply that force by the number of zombies you want to raise and bada-bing bada-boom zombie army.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do the blood transfusion mundanely, but require the proper runic energy to "start up" the subject.  It wouldn't matter how the rune is activated, just that the energy translates to at least animation, if not technically life.

Answer (score 1):

### Go back to first principles: runes are read

To tap into the potency of an idea, you need to think about where it came from.  *WHY* are wands, rods, runes, scrolls, herbs, and potions magic?  Now the answer varies case to case.  Potions and herbs [date back a long way](https://www.bradshawfoundation.com/news/origins.php?id=Neanderthal-use-of-medicinal-plants).  My guess is the power of the rod traces back to the days when someone wanted a tomb ten rods long, and everything started with the overseers holding up their rods to copy the head architect's length because colonnades look nicer that way.  And runes and scrolls?

I picture a group of wandering adventurers in an ancient time standing in front of a tomb decorated in weird mystical symbols.  Suddenly their shaman gets a faraway look, staring at images in his mind no one else can see, as he struggles to tap into the power of the runes.  The spirit of a dead man enters him, and he begins to speak in a strange halting monotone, sweating with the effort:  *"dear-jerry-if-you-can-read-this-we-put-the-gold-under-the-big-oak-tree"*.  Now people can scoff all they like about whether shamans really can speak with the spirits of the dead, but two feet under those arching roots -- GOLD!  That's a magic you can sink your teeth into, even if the shamans keep you in the dark about some of the details.

So let's go with the idea that runes are *read*.  I mean, there's no fundamental essence of a squiggle with a cross-branch next to a squiggle with a dot over it and so forth that makes them summon fire.  Instead, there is some spirit, soul, essence, astral being, manitou, demigod, entity, algorithm, mechanism, whatever that can see fire is requested and carries out the command.  The reader may exist in a different place (underworld, parallel dimension, plane of existence) so that the entirety of the intent is not known; it may only see the rune shine through like a hand pressed to the back of a mirror.  But there is some tendency, for whatever reason, for it to go along with what the rune says.

Answer (score 0):

Look at "apply force to rune…"; the action, not the result.

Newton says: 'A body persists (as is)… unless acted upon by a force…'  What force matters how?

Whether 'energy' here is physical, psychic or what matters how?

Can "blood (life energy)" become force?

Transfusions are - more so in your exposition - changes in energy.

Physics tells you energy is the capacity to do work; power is the rate at which energy is expended; force is the result of applying power.

How is "blood (life energy)" not energy, changing which changes power and so, force?